# How to obtain fully indipendent outputs on two columns without using tables

Tags: tables, two-column

I have the following problem: I would like to find a way to have as an output two columns, where the content of each column is written independently of the other (i.e. no tables way of writing).

To be (hopefully) more precise, I would like to have the following output:

```
     Left              Right 
--------------    --------------
1. ******         1. ******
2. ******         2. ******   
3. ******         
4. ******
5. ****** 


---------------------------------
```

(where the space left below item 5 wants to point out that there has to be the possibility to have still space on that column) possibly on a page in landscape mode, where `Left` and `Right` are the header of each column, and the content below each of them is insterted separately, i.e. rather in this sort of way (just to give an idea):

```
\section{Left}
\begin{enumerate}
\item *******
\item *******
\item *******
\item *******
\item *******
\end{enumerate}

\section{Right}
\begin{enumerate}
\item *******
\item *******
\end{enumerate}
```

I have the feeling that twocolumns does not really make the job, because it simply takes the text and puts it in two columns, hence, I would not get the space below item 5 – if needed – as I want. Still, I would like to avoid tables (I find rather cumbersome to write what I would like to with them).

Thus, is there a way to get it?

Thank you for your time.

PS: I am afraid the question could look rather messy. Of course I will be more than happy to clarify any point if needed.

Comment: You could use two `minipages` side by side, or `multicolumn`s

Comment: package `paracol` https://www.ctan.org/pkg/paracol

Comment: Another option is `tabbing` environment.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for all these options. I will check what is the one that suits best my needs.

Comment: @TeXnician Thanks for having reminded me this question.  Actually I did not find a solution. I will check again and – eventually – insert an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: multiple columns]

Here's the minipage solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.475\textwidth}
{\Large\bfseries Left}
\begin{enumerate}
\item *******
\item *******
\item *******
\item *******
\item *******
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.475\textwidth}
{\Large\bfseries Right}
\begin{enumerate}
\item *******
\item *******
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

and `multicols`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
{\Large\bfseries Left}
\begin{enumerate}
\item *******
\item *******
\item *******
\item *******
\item *******
\end{enumerate}
\columnbreak
{\Large\bfseries Right}
\begin{enumerate}
\item *******
\item *******
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Btw: You can still use `\section` (just replaced it for a previous try).

Comment: Wow, this is great. May I ask you how can I get a dividing line between the columns?

Comment: @Kolmin If you decided in favour of one method you should ask a new question with that. Just out of my mind: with `multicols` you can do `\setlength{\columnseprule}{.4pt}` or the like.